# How to make this question better

Tags: discussion

This question [Can a satellite utilize gravity gradient stabiliazation and passive stabilization together?](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/30922/can-a-satellite-utilize-gravity-gradient-stabiliazation-and-passive-stabilizatio) is severely flawed, despite some attempt to improve it.

Since the flaws are often found in the author's questions, I'd like to take some time to give some generic advises that could help making better questions; using this question as an exemple.

Comment: I wrote a new one here and I will take the time to address the issues you stated ASAP. I got suspended for minor stuff in physics which effected some others because of the parent sight was also effected. Maybe by the time I made it here to SE.SE I learned enough not to make the same mistakes. I still maintain my innocents on the voting fraud by sock puppeting.   https://space.stackexchange.com/a/31614/18879

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Can the Mariner 3 (I should have used Mariner 4 for an example but we'll stick to 3 which also has the passive stabilization vanes)

Here, there is an exemple of 2 (identical) spacecrafts.

- The whole sentence in parenthesis add nothing to the question

  => Remove it
- The question actually has nothing to do with Mariner

  => Use "A spacecraft with solar vanes, similar to mariner 3" or similar sentence

> be tethered by a long pole or line

We enter the domain of science fiction. This is fine per see, but makes it hard to narrow down an answer, since it assume we have technologies still unknown to us.

> to utilize the gravity gradient

The tether and gravity gradient are two things that have little in common, and not directly related, or applicable to each other.

- My guess is that you didn't understood correctly the gravity gradient concept.

  => Make sure you understand them before trying to mix it with other concepts.

> and radiation from it's vanes to reduce the need of propellants to maintain orientation to the Earth?

- You narrowed down the subject of your question to one single effect. This is good.

> The long pole would have solar vanes

- Why have solar vanes both on the spacecraft and the poles ?
- This add unnecessary complexity to the question

  => Try to make your problem simpler, not more complicated, **especially** when it is hypothetical.

  => Eventually, add it in a second part. Ex "Can a spacecraft be able to do A? Would B help ?"

> at either end

- Either end ? Surely you don't mean to put solar vanes on the ground (the other end of the cable)

> that can use gravity

- Solar vanes function with solar pressure, not gravity. This makes no sense

> to adjust altitude

- Surely you meant attitude (orientation) ?

> and position

- Solar vanes and gravity gradient are meant to control the orientation, not the positon. Once again you are mixing up concepts

> by turning with against or solo up down and around the pole

- This sentence makes no sense. Always try to make simple sentence. Ex: "By moving around the pole"

> to change the way radiation hits the vanes

- The vanes of Mariner 3 where actuated, there is no need to move the spacraft around (or was it the poles with the vanes?)

> while creating the imbalance you mention

- Who is you ? In this context, name the subject.

> Doing this should be able to create lift

- Lift is a force used in atmospheric flight.

  => Replace with "Force", "pressure

> and change orientation eliminating the need for propellants.

## Generic tips

- Do not mix concepts if not well understood
- Do not try to add additional parameters
- Do re read yourself. Multiple times
- After an edit, re read the whole question
- Make sure you understand each concepts separately
- Use appropriate tenses, and conditional form when appropriate
- Avoid completely changing a question. Sometime creating a new one is better.
- Simplify your questions; eventually adding complexity in follow ups
- Do not add off topic/non relevant informations (eg: vanes move by magnetic [...]) the fact that they move with magnetic forces is irrelevant to the question)
- ...